# Weird time format in Quick Time

Tags: macos, quicktime

I have time displaying like this:

[image]

in some my videos in **.mp4** format (not at all of them). What is it about & how to change it to normal view? OS X 10.11.4

P.S. All is fine in **Elmedia Player** (it's the same video opened).

[image]

Comment: Do all videos played in QT have a messed-up time format or just this one?

Comment: No, some have & some don't.

Comment: What duration and position should it actually be?

Comment: Please, see the updated original post.

Comment: Does this happen for videos less than an hour long? And to check a theory, what language/region is your system in? Do you use 12-hour or 24-hour time in your system?

Comment: Nope, it happens in videos that are longer than 1 hour, I think & use 12-hour time in my machine. I try to change the time to 24 format & everything changes to what I want, but, what's happened in 12-hour format?

Comment: @k1r8r0wn QuickTime Player has had an issue with certain Language/Region configurations for the past few releases of OS X (it really hasn't been updated much since 2014). What happens varies, for example it shows "aK:00:00" on my Japanese configuration.